# how i can fix this confirm password?

Tags: javascript, html

i have some html code here..

```
<tr>
   <td align="right" for="psw">Password</td>
   <td>
      <input style="width: 100%"
       type="password" 
       id="password" 
       name="password" 
       pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" 
       title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 6 or more characters"
       onchange="check_pass()" 
       required/>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" for="confirm_password">Confirm password</td>
        <td>
        <input style="width: 100%" 
        type="password" 
        id="confirm_password" 
        name="confirm_password" 
        onchange="check_pass()"
        required/>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

i got a problem on confir_password

here my js code :

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("password");
myInput.onfocus = function() {
document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}
myInput.onblur = function() {
document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

this one is for confirm_password..

```
 var myInput = document.getElementById("password")
 , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

 function validatePassword(){
 if(myInput.value != confirm_password.value) {
 confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
 } else {
 confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
 }
}

myInput.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

i don't have any idea to fix this. it seems like not function at all for confirm_password.
 hope somebody can help me.

Comment: The `for` attribute belongs in a `<label>`, not `<td>`.

Comment: oh forgot to tell there that i'm doing the form inside the table

Comment: It looks like the validation function should work. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: do i need to remove {for} or change to any other tag?

Comment: It's just being ignored, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: The right way to do the labels is: `<td align="right"><label for="password">Password</label></td>`

Comment: You can't have two `onchange` functions. Either `onchange="check_pass()` or `myInput.onchange = validatePassword;`.

Comment: If you want multiple functions, use `addEventListener()`, it adds instead of replacing.

Comment: what is the expected result? what result do you get? what is your check_pass() function do? don't you need parenthesis at the function call in your onchange and onkeyup?

Comment: expected result is if we didn't put the same password then a message will popup told the password is wrong. But the result i got when i entered different password in each colomn it didnt tell the password is wrong as long as the pattern for {password}  is fully filled